# Using SYCL 1.2 in MacOS

Tags: macos, sycl

I want to start using SYCL,  but so far I found that one needs to install [ComputeCpp](https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides) and it only supports Ubuntu, CentOS, and Windows. What are the alternatives for using SYCL on MacOS Catalina?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Summary

Multiple SYCL implementation support MacOS today, although they only support CPU devices.

GPU device support is not available because Apple does not support the back-end dependencies available on Linux or Windows.

## Details

[triSYCL](https://github.com/triSYCL/triSYCL) supports MacOS but only CPU execution. I use it frequently. You may need to switch C++ compilers since the native toolchain might not work.  https://github.com/triSYCL/triSYCL

[hipSYCL](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL) also supports CPU execution and should work on MacOS.  [Pull request #271](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/pull/271) should have details.

We did some work to get Intel DPC++ to build on MacOS (see [Issue #258](https://github.com/intel/llvm/issues/258)) but it’s not there yet. [Issue #982](https://github.com/intel/llvm/issues/982) is tracking MacOS support.

I routinely use all the SYCL compilers for Linux on my Mac laptop inside of virtual machines but that is still CPU-only execution.

## Possibilities

The most promising route to GPU support of SYCL on MacOS requires translating to [Metal Shader Language (MSL)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/), because Apple OpenCL doesn’t support SPIR-V. This can be done with [SPIRV-Cross](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Cross) but nobody has implemented it in any SYCL compiler as far as I know.

Note that translating kernels from SPIR-V to MSL is only part of the answer.  The other requirement is runtime support for kernel loading, etc.  Some of these issues are apparent in https://github.com/bobpepin/opencl-osx, although this is merely a problem statement, not a solution.

If Apple were to support CUDA (unlikely, based on https://gizmodo.com/apple-and-nvidia-are-over-1840015246), then the PTX back-ends of hipSYCL or DPC++ might work, but I am not aware of any attempts along these lines with older Macs that support(ed) CUDA.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering Jeff,  I decided for hipSYCL and seems like it installed properly. However, when compiling the tests, I am getting  error messages regarding mathematical functions, e.g. /usr/local/bin/../include/CL/../hipSYCL/sycl/math.hpp:284:63: error: use of undeclared identifier '__cosf'
HIPSYCL_DEFINE_FAST_SINGLE_PRECISION_FUNCTION(cos, sycl::cos, __cosf); 

Any known fix for it?

Comment: Create a GitHub issue. But it may have a fix already. Look at existing issues for that error message.

Answer (score 1):

ComputeCpp is one of several SYCL implementations, the full list is [here](https://sycl.tech/#get-sycl).

None of the implementations currently support macOS, this is mainly because Apple plans to drop support for OpenCL and only provide support for Metal as its interface to hardware. You can however dual boot your Apple machine with Linux and use that to develop with any of the SYCL implementations (including ComputeCpp).